# What to add dashboard to drilldown

Tags: grafana

I am trying to add a Drilldown Link to a Grafana panel.

Sadly this does not seem obvious and/or documented.
What I tried is setting `type` to `dashboard` and :

- Setting `Dashboard` field to: `dashboardslug`
- Setting `Dashboard` field to: `/dashboardslug`
- Setting `Dashboard` field to: `/iZeiUHhWk/dashboardslug`
- Setting `Dashboard` field to: `/d/iZeiUHhWk/dashboardslug`

All of these resulted in a link to "undefined" Dashboard.
Can anyone explain what `Dashboard` is supposed to reference?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this: https://grafana.com/docs/v3.1/reference/graph/

It seems to be the **name**.

Which of course means, that you will get problems when renaming a Dashboard :(